# Chef: create cookbooks into repo

Tags: chef-infra

I was using `knife` in order to create cookbooks into my repo. `knife` is deprecated now, and I'm using `chef generate cookbook` instead.

I'm facing up with several issues:

1. My repo is located in a custom folder (not under `~/.chef`). So when I'm using `chef generate cookbook` is places the cookbook into `~/.chef`. Using `knife` I was able to set up where my cookbooks had to be placed using `knife.rb`. Is there anyway to get this behavior using `chef`?
2. Is there anyway to delete or remove this cookbook?
3. I don't quite figure out how to upload my cookbooks using `chef` tool. Is `knife` absolutly deprecated? Which's the role of berkshelf into a repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookbooks can be created using chef, berks or knife. Since knife is deprecated using chef is preferred way. As a note even if you created cookbook using knife it doesn't upload to your chef sever unless you do `knife cookbook upload cookbookname`. You can verify it using `knife cookbook list` which will list latest version of cookbook in server or add `-a` in list command so that all versions in server are displayed. So you can create cookbook using `chef generate cookbookname`, update with your changes and upload to chef using `knife cookbook upload cookbookname` itself

Answer (score 1):

you can just simply do `chef generate /path/to/cookbook` and just modify your desire path. 
do `knife -h` to see all commands for generating cookbook or delete them

```
knife cookbook delete COOKBOOK VERSION (options)
```

Are you using chef-solo or chef server?